# HPLIP broken with Acroread, or broken in general?

Tags: linux, printing, printer, network-printer

A HP printer that worked perfectly fine with acroread previously on the same system has stopped working when using acroread.

Gentoo stable, running 3.18.11.

Printer: HP Officejet Pro 8100 connected over Ethernet

HPLIP: net-print/hplip-3.14.10

I can print from Firefox and from the command line, e.g. using:

```
   echo "hello" | lpr
```

However, printing from acroread silently fails.

In /var/log/cups/access_log I see only benign messages:

```
localhost - - [03/May/2015:14:49:07 +0200] "POST /printers/Officejet_Pro_8100 HTTP/1.1" 200 506 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [03/May/2015:14:49:07 +0200] "POST /printers/Officejet_Pro_8100 HTTP/1.1" 200 209178 Send-Document successful-ok
```

The same holds true for CUPS at localhost:631, no errors indicating any issues.

The same holds true for the hplip included GUI based tool, it shows the printer having received a job and that it is in the state of "printing", except there is no physical printing going on.

USE flags for hplip:

```
 * Found these USE flags for net-print/hplip-3.14.10:
 U I
 + + X                        : Enables scanner GUI dependencies with USE="scanner" where media-gfx/xsane is preferred over media-gfx/sane-frontends
 + + doc                      : Build documentation
 - - fax                      : Enable fax on multifunction devices which support it
 + + hpcups                   : Build the hpcups driver for cups (by HP)
 + + hpijs                    : Build the IJS driver for cups (Foomatic)
 - - kde                      : Enables kde-misc/skanlite as scanner GUI with USE="scanner X"
 + + libnotify                : Enables desktop notifications
 - - libusb0                  : Depend on virtual/libusb:0. Some old printers do not work with virtual/libusb:1
 - - minimal                  : Only build internal hpijs/hpcups driver (not recommended at all, make sure you know what you are doing)
 - - parport                  : Enable parallel port for devices which require it
 + + policykit                : Enable PolicyKit authentication support
 + + python_targets_python2_7 : Build with Python 2.7
 + + qt4                      : Enable graphical interface using Qt 4
 - - scanner                  : Enable scanner on multifunction devices which support it
 + + snmp                     : Add support for net-analyzer/net-snmp which enables this driver to work over networks (both for server and client)
 - - static-ppds              : Use statically-generated PPDs instead of Dynamic PPDs. Although this is deprecated some printers may still need it
                                to work properly. Use this flag if hp-setup fails to find/create a valid PPD file
```

acroread USE flags:

```
 + + html          : HTML support and help reading capability (only for x86).
 + + ldap          : Add LDAP support (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol)
 - - linguas_ja    : Japanese locale
 - - linguas_ko    : Korean locale
 - - linguas_zh_CN : Chinese locale for Peoples Republic of China
 - - linguas_zh_TW : Chinese locale for Taiwan
 + + nsplugin      : Build plugin for browsers supporting the Netscape plugin architecture (that is almost any modern browser)
```

hp-doctor shows the following errors, but please note that these errors have always been present since the printer was working and I doubt they are relevant:

```
 error: avahi-utils   avahi-utils               OPTIONAL        -               -               MISSING    'avahi-utils needs to be installed'
 error: reportlab     Python-PDF-Lib            OPTIONAL        2.0             -               MISSING    'reportlab needs to be installed'

 error: pil           Python-Image-Lib          OPTIONAL        -               -               MISSING    'pil needs to be installed'
```

What I have tried:

Physically turning the printer on and off.
Using a different computer also running Gentoo (same results, works but not with acroread).
Adding the hpijs USE flag to hplip (was not needed before, appears to make no difference now).

Why doesn't this work? Is it a problem with acroread, is it a problem with hplip, or a software problem with the physical printer?